# No authorization token was found when res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I have two applications, both on Nodejs. One front-end and other back-end.
My back-end app is protected with token access using express-jwt and jsonwebtoken middlewares.

My problem is: I am making a request from front-end to back-end passing the token on header, back-end accepts the request and respond properly. Then in the front-end I redirect the response to an specific page (*res.redirect('/')*), in that moment I get the error ***UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found***

My front-end request:

```
/* Authentication */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // request login service
    request({
        uri: env.getUrl() + "/user",
        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '.concat(global.token)
        },
        form: { login : req.body.login, pwd : req.body.pwd }
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            logger.error(error);
            res.render("error", {message: "Error getting user" }); 
        }
        else {
            if(body){
                req.session.usuario = JSON.parse(body);
                res.redirect("/");
            } else {
                res.render("login", {message: "Login Failed" });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know why this happen. Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found.

Anytime the my front-end app makes a request to the back-end side (api) the user logged in front-end is validated against back-end and so the fron-end's session is updated as well. Which means that every request is actually two requests:

1. One as the real request the app is doing.
2. The request validating the user logged on front-end in order to be sure that user exists.

This update (second point) was made without providing a token.

Answer (score 1):

A redirect (via [res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)) issues a new HTTP request. This means that the `Authorization` header is empty. This results in the ***UnauthorizedError*** error.

To fix this, you have two options:

**1. Pass the token in the URI**
You can issue the redirect with the token passed in the URL in this way:

```
res.redirect("/?access_token=" + global.token);
```

**2. Set the header before the redirect**
You can set the `'Authorization'` header before making the redirect request:

```
req.session.access_token = global.token;
```

Comment: A redirect (via res.redirect) issues a new HTTP request, agreed. But that res.redirect is done in front-end side, which means that the *res* object is from front-end side. My understanding is that it should not call back-end again. Moreover, I have tried the second option putting token again in *req* object but in headers parameter, not session. It didn't work.

Comment: Would it be because of both applications are in localhost? (but on different ports)